# Unable to find host target(s) for Extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods

## Report

**What did you do?**

I tried to run the **pod install** command

**What did you expect to happen?**

Install all pod dependencies correctly like the 1.1.1 version do.

**What happened instead?**

> [!] Unable to find host target(s) for myExtension1, myExtension2.   Please add the host targets for the embedded targets to the Podfile.
>   Certain kinds of targets require a host target. A host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target. These are example types of targets that need a host target:
>   - Framework
>   - App Extension
>   - Watch OS 1 Extension
>   - Messages Extension (except when used with a Messages Application)

**CocoaPods Environment**

```
Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.2.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-darwin15]
    RubyGems : 2.4.5.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73)
       Xcode : 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
         Git : git version 2.13.0
Ruby lib dir : /Users/dogo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 08682dc5b65d664048f43d7886a018856c692b63
```

**Installation Source**

```
Executable Path: /Users/dogo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/pod
```

**Plugins**

```
claide-plugins        : 0.9.2
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.2.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
slather               : 2.4.2
```

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'  

project 'MyProject', 'DebugProduction' => :release , 'Integrated' => :release , 'Mock' => :release, 'DebugMock' => :debug  

platform :ios, '8.0'  

inhibit_all_warnings!  

def all_pods  
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'  
pod 'AFNetworking'  
pod 'AMPopTip', '~> 1.0.0'  
pod 'BBBadgeBarButtonItem', '~> 1.2'  
pod 'Bricks', '~> 0.1.2'  
pod 'bricks-Mantle', '~> 0.1.0'  
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.2.0'  
pod 'Crashlytics'  
pod 'CustomIOSAlertView'  
pod 'Fabric'  
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.16.0'  
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.16.0'  
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.16.0'  
pod 'FDKeychain', '~> 1.0.0'  
pod 'FSCalendar'  
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.17.0'  
pod 'GoogleConversionTracking', '~> 3.4.0'  
pod 'GoogleMaps', '2.3.1'  
pod 'HockeySDK', '4.1.6'  
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'  
pod 'LGPlusButtonsView'  
pod 'MaryPopin', '1.4.2'  
pod 'MBProgressHUD'  
pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'  
pod 'MMWHaleImageCropper', '~> 0.1'  
pod 'NSStringMask', '1.2'  
pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 1.1.0'  
pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 1.7.0'  
pod 'Realm', '~> 2.3.0'  
pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4'  
pod 'RegExCategories', '~> 1.0'  
pod 'SMXMLDocument', '~> 1.1'  
pod 'SpotlightHandler', :git => 'https://github.com/renatosarro/SpotlightHandler'  
pod 'SRMonthPicker', '~> 0.2.10'  
pod 'TLInputsChainHelper', :git => 'https://github.com/thiagolioy/TLInputsChainHelper.git'  
pod 'TLJsonFactory'  
pod 'UITintedButton'  
pod 'XMLDictionary', '1.4'  
pod 'ZBarSDK'  
pod 'ZSWTaggedString', '~> 1.1'  
pod 'ZSWTappableLabel', '1.3'  
end  

target :MyProject do  
all_pods  
end  

target :'MyProject-cal' do  
all_pods  
end   

target :MyProjectExtension do  
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.17.0'  
end  

target :MyProject2 do  
all_pods  
end  

target :'MyProject2-cal' do  
all_pods  
end   

target :MyProjectExtension2 do  
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.17.0'  
end  

target :MyProjectTests do  
inherit! :search_paths  
pod 'Expecta'  
pod 'OCMock'  
pod 'Specta', '1.0.5'  
pod 'TLJsonFactory'  
end
```

Comment: clean build, restart pc, and try again! I had a similar problem that got fixed by that

Comment: i am try this but not working pls help me. i am put question on this point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607730/please-add-the-host-targets-for-the-embedded-targets-to-the-podfile-pls-help-me

Answer (score 30):

**The problem is not in the podfile, but in the project!**

To fix:

- Go to XCode
- Select your HOST target.
- Open the target's 'General' page
- In the 'Embedded Binaries' section, make sure your EXTENSION target is present. 
  [image]
- In your Podfile you should have:

  `target 'HostApp' do
    ....
    target 'YourExtension' do
      ....
    end
  end`

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me because I had a target for an extension that was de-activated (removed as a dependency for the main target) in my Podfile.

Removing the target fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem. However I didn't want my extension to be 'deactivated' - the fix for me was to re-add the extension in the `Target Dependencies` section of my main target in the `Build Phases` section.

Comment: i am try this but not working pls help me. i am put question on this point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607730/please-add-the-host-targets-for-the-embedded-targets-to-the-podfile-pls-help-me

Answer (score 6):

For me to solve he issue I had to remove the appex of the extension from the host app's Embedded binaries and add it again (because the issue happened after solving merge conflicts)

Then I ran "pod install", and it worked

Comment: This worked perfectly. I got all kind of errors regarding frameworks, intents, widget but in fact all I had to do was removing all appex from one iOS target and re-adding them and now everything works again.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add extension to both Build Phases -> Dependencies and Build Phases -> Embed App Extensions for you Main app target