# Please add the host targets for the embedded targets to the Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

My project is in Swift 2.0. I am try all possible ways but not found any solution.

My pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '8.0'
# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!


def available_pods
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'Instabug'
    pod "TSMessages"
    pod 'AsyncSwift' , :git => 'https://github.com/duemunk/Async.git'

    pod 'Onboard' # not used
    pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet' # not used
    pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu'
    pod 'Kanna', :git => 'https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna.git'
    pod 'HanekeSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift.git'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', :git => 'https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper.git'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'SCLAlertView'
    pod 'ImageLoader'
    pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', :git => 'https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView.git'
    pod 'ActiveLabel'
    pod 'MWFeedParser'
    pod "SwiftElegantDropdownMenu"
    pod 'SwiftHEXColors'
    pod 'UITextView+Placeholder'
    pod "AFDateHelper"
    pod 'DateTools'
    pod "SwiftDate", "~> 2.0"
    pod 'APAddressBook/Swift'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'PusherSwift', git: 'https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift.git', branch: 'push-notifications'

end

def available_pods_exc
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'Kanna', :git => 'https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna.git'
    pod 'AsyncSwift' , :git => 'https://github.com/duemunk/Async.git'
end



target 'link' do
    available_pods

end

target 'ReadLaterExtension' do
    available_pods_exc
    end

target 'Link Tests' do
    pod 'Quick', '0.3.1'
    pod 'Nimble'
end
```

I found below error

```
[!] Unable to find host target(s) for ReadLaterExtension. Please add the host targets for the embedded targets to the Podfile.
Certain kinds of targets require a host target. A host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target. These are example types of targets that need a host target:

- Framework
- App Extension
- Watch OS 1 Extension
- Messages Extension (except when used with a Messages Application)
```

Answer (score 9):

**The problem is not in the podfile, but in the project!**

To fix:

- Go to XCode
- Select your HOST target.
- Open the target's 'General' page
- In the 'Embedded Binaries' section, make sure your EXTENSION target is present.
  [image]
- In your Podfile you should have:

  `target 'HostApp' do
    ....
    target 'YourExtension' do
      ....
    end
  end`

Comment: After all above, same error; **solution** was to follow the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607896/8740349) as well (Xcode target's dependency section did not include extension, but everything except cocoapods works even without said dependency).

Comment: Also, editing `Podfile` to put extension-target in host-app-target is **not** required (at least not at time of writing, cocoapods version `1.7.3`).

Answer (score 4):

In order to disable building/running the NSExtension you build, you should:

1. Click the project file in the project navigator
2. Click the containing app target (the one you DO want to run)
3. Click Build Phases tab
4. Open Target Dependencies
5. Remove the extension (the one you DON'T want to run)
6. To bring it back, simply click the + sign in the same place and
   re-add it.

In my case working sucessfully

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I would like to add one reason I just discovered for this error message:

In the Main Targets Build Phases the section `Embed App Extensions` has to be above the `[CP] Copy Pods Resources` and `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworkds`.